# jQuery unbind event handler does not work

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling

I am adding nodes (divs) to a DOM tree dynamically and attaching event listeners via jQuery (either delegated or not). The problem is that I cannot unbind those listeners, and as a result, they pile up. Here is a sample code, I cannot find any mistakes:

```js
$(function() {
  var theTXT = '<div data-abc="tester">click here</div>';
  $("#loader").on('click', doClick);
  function doClick() {
    $("body").append(theTXT);
    $('[data-abc="tester"]').off('click', redoClick);
    $('[data-abc="tester"]').on('click', redoClick);
    function redoClick() {
      console.log("hi");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader">load</div>
```

Now, if I move the redoClick() handler outside the doClick() handler, everything works OK.
Any help would be appreciated, so that I can understand why .off() does not work.

Comment: Why are you declaring a function inside another function? oO

Comment: What's the goal? For each added 'click here' div to only log 'hi' the first time it's clicked?

Comment: @ZivWeissman I prefer to constrain the scope of vars and functions, that's why

Comment: I could remove all click listeners, like that:

$('[data-abc="tester"]').off('click');

but I'd rather avoid such a crude solution.

Comment: @j08691 No, the problem appeared in a quite complicated form, parts of which are created dynamically. This is an over-simplified version of the problematic behavior of .off(). What I don't understand, is that on() sees the redoClick() handler and registers the event, whereas off() does not(!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the "off", the problem is with the event handler.

Because you are defining it inside the function, it will be "out of scope" after function call will end, therefore the off cannot turn off this specific handler.

If you put it outside the function it works as planned, another option is to remove it:

```js
$(function() {
  var theTXT = '<div data-abc="tester">click here</div>';
  $("#loader").on('click', doClick);
  function doClick() {
    $("body").append(theTXT);
    $('[data-abc="tester"]').off('click'); //remove the handler
    $('[data-abc="tester"]').on('click', redoClick);
    function redoClick() {
      console.log("hi");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader">load</div>
```

> Now, if I move the redoClick() handler outside the doClick() handler,
>   everything works OK.

Because it was declared outside the function so the .off can access it.

> But here's my question: how come on() works? What am I missing here?

The first time you are clicking you will have an handler lets say doClick#1, first the "off" will try to remove doClick#1 (not binded) - then the on will click in, binding doClick#1. The second time it runs you will create doClick#2, and the off again will try to remove doClick#2 - not found, while the on will add doClick#2 (so you will have #1+#2 and so on)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried those solutions already and I confirm that they work. But here's my question: how come on() works? What am I missing here?

Comment: because you are declaring the "on" in the same scope that you define the "doClick", while the "off" will be on the next time your function will create another instance of "doClick" @ThomasMavrofides - edited my answer hope it is clearer

Comment: Got it now, thanks, I think you're right. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Glad to help. Just don't forget to mark as Answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, dummy me, the answer to the specific problem (i.e. how NOT to re-attach event listeners to a bunch of elements), was dead simple. It hit me this morning. Instead of using

```
$('[data-abc="tester"]').on('click', redoClick);
```

I should use:

```
$('[data-abc="tester"]').last().on('click', redoClick);
```

That did it, no off() needed